# Calling Azure mobile services asynchronously from a Console Application

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, console-application, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to have a console application call Azure mobile services to perform an insert in the DB (a test prototype I am trying out. My eventual goal is to have the console app be run on a regular schedule as an Azure webjob).

The code snippet below does an insert. When I comment out the Console.readline(), the program just runs and exits but does nothing (fails to insert). When I have the readline() in there, it can successfully insert. I am guessing this is because I am calling an async method and control just flows out of main even before async method has a chance to complete.

In the eventual application I am trying to develop, the console app would kick off a lengthy update operation, wait for it to complete and then exit until the azure web jobs scheduler runs it again. What is the recommended way to accomplish the 'await' here?

```
class Program
{
    static IMobileServiceTable<TodoItem> todoTable;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
        "mymobileservice url",
        "my application ID"
        );

        todoTable = MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>();

        todoTable.InsertAsync(new TodoItem() { Text = "Console Item 2", Complete = false });

        //Console.ReadLine();

    }        
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Console app, I recommend placing all of your actual logic (including error handling) into a `MainAsync` method and then calling `Task.Wait` from `Main`, as such:

```
class Program
{
  static IMobileServiceTable<TodoItem> todoTable;

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    MainAsync(args).Wait();
  }

  static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
        "mymobileservice url",
        "my application ID"
      );

      todoTable = MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>();

      await todoTable.InsertAsync(new TodoItem() { Text = "Console Item 2", Complete = false });
    }        
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting");
        Task todo = asyncMethod();
        todo.ContinueWith((str) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(str.Status.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("Main end");
        });
        todo.Wait();
    }

    public async static Task<string> asyncMethod()
    {
        MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
        "mymobileservice url",
        "my application ID"
        );
        todoTable = MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>();
        await todoTable.InsertAsync(new TodoItem() { Text = "Console Item 2", Complete = false });
        return "finished";
    }
}
```

More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606.aspx).

Comment: Thank you! I will try to figure out what this is doing and give it a try.

Comment: The thing this is doing is allowing you to write normal async/await pattern. You need to do it this way since you can't make Main async

Answer (score 2):

It looks like in your console application you really want to wait for the response. In a UI-based application you can't really "wait" for a network operation to finish, otherwise the thread on which it started (the UI thread) will be blocked and the application will appear "hung". But on a console, you can just ask for the `.Result` property of a `Task` (or call `.Wait()`) and the result will be the same:

```
class Program
{
    static IMobileServiceTable<TodoItem> todoTable;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MobileServiceClient MobileService = new MobileServiceClient(
            "mymobileservice url",
            "my application ID"
        );
        todoTable = MobileService.GetTable<TodoItem>();
        var item = new TodoItem() { Text = "Console Item 2", Complete = false };
        todoTable.InsertAsync(item).Wait();

        var itemId = item.Id;
        var retrieved = todoTable.LookupAsync(itemId).Result;
        //Console.ReadLine();
    }        
}
```